# How to create xs:durations with variables in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the correct syntax here?
I want to apply my template to all flights with a duration of more than 8 hours.
I think it should work that way, but I cant find anything about line 4 and it seems wrong.
I know I could go and transform everything to minutes and compare it that way, but I wanted to try the duration function.

```
<xsl: for-each select="flight">
    <xsl: variable name="time" select="xs:time(arrival)-xs:time(departure)"/>
    <xsl: variable name="timezone" select="id(@nr)/number(timezone)"/>
    <xsl: variable name="duration" select="$time + xs:duration("PT$timezoneH")"/>
        <xsl: if test="$duration>"PT8H"">
             <xsl: apply-template select="."/>
        </xsl: if>          
</xsl: for-each>

<xsl: template select="flight">
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: See whether the examples in http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/chapter20.html help (XPath, XQuery and XSLT have the same underlying data model)

Comment: An example of your data would also help us give you a more complete answer. ([minimum complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: Isn't it obvious? This: `xs:duration("PT$timezoneH")` takes a very unexpected string value as the argument.  Maybe you wanted something like: `'PT3H'`?. Also, you have nested double quotes and this is even lexically incorrect. Here is one example: `xs:duration(concat('PT', $hours, 'H'))`